# How to delete NULL items from Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf

Somehow `WPF Canvas` has a lot of items which are `NULL`.

Is there some way **to delete/remove it**?

Comment: I think it would be wise to figure out how they can contain null items in the first place. Instead of trying to remove, get rid of the cause.

Comment: @dowhilefor U are right, bro... Well... I cannot manage it at all. I just want to delete NULL items

Comment: Loop trough the Children collection and remove them.

Comment: @NestorArturo Yes I know. But how I can identify them? Could u give me any sample code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your Canvas has `null` items because it is bound to a data source that has `null` items

It would be far better to remove the `null` items from the data source before binding the data, however if that isn't possible, then try using a `Converter` that removes `null` items from the collection to do the binding.

All it really needs to do is loop through the items and check if each one is `null`. If so, remove it using `.RemoveAt(index)`

```
var i = 0;
while(i < list.Items.Count)
{
    if (list.items[i] == null)
        list.RemoveAt(i);
    else
        i++; // don't increase i if you're removing an item
}
```